# "undefined" error for cordovaRef installing Badge plugin iOS/iphone

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I get "undefined" for cordovaRef after

```
var cordovaRef = window.PhoneGap || window.Cordova || window.cordova;
alert(cordovaRef);
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

I went through the general tutorial how to install Phonegap plugins and read the read me file but it still doesn't work. Cordova 1.6.1 does work (tested with geoloc and camera) on iPhone device (and simulator geoloc). But in the phone gap plugins .zip there are IOS and iPhone folders. Why is it so? The Badge plugin in the iPhone folders seems to be older than in the IOS folder. I used that from IOS folder.

Sorry for the missing tags and unformatted code..

1. Plugins folder: I dragged the Badge.h and Badge.m files into Plugins folder into Xcode 4.2, chose "Create groups for any added folders, Add to targets (com.myproject), copy items into destination group's folder.
2. WWW folder: copied Badge.js into the www folder and included it into the index.html file

where I test it with a button click

```
window.plugins.badge.set(6);
```

Cordova.plist (cordova 1.6.1): Added tags to Cordova.plist (erased brackets)

```
<dict>
<key> Badge </key>
<string>Badge </string>
 ...
 </dict>
```

But it doesn't work. I get "undefined" for cordovaRef after

```
var cordovaRef = window.PhoneGap || window.Cordova || window.cordova;
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I imported the cordova.js after I imported the plugin js file.